# I can't get a value to stay in my $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, arrays, echo, associative, indexed

I am trying to get values out of an indexed array, but when I use a variable as the index (which is equal to an index in the array), it does not appear. I get an `Undefined Index` Error. Why is this happening? Does anyone know? Thanks!

I have the following code:

```
$bookarray = array();
                $books = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM books");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($books)){
                    $bookarray[$row['bookID']] = array(
                        'title' => $row['title'],
                        'author' => $row['author'],
                        'price' => $row['price']
                    );
                }
                echo"<hr>";
                print_r($bookarray);
                echo"<hr>";
                echo $bookarray[5]['title']."<br />";


                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $cartedbook){
                    echo $cartedbook;
                    echo $bookarray[$cartedbook]['title'];
                    echo "<br />";
                }
```

This is the output:

#### Books

---

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Java 2 for Pro Deelopers
        [author] => Michael Morgan
        [price] => 34.99
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Installing XAMPP
        [author] => Thomas Down
        [price] => 24.99
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Alice Through the Looking Glass
        [author] => Louis Carroll
        [price] => 72.35
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [title] => Quantum Mechanics in 124 Hours
        [author] => Neils Bohr
        [price] => 24.99
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [title] => PHP For Fun And Profit
        [author] => Thomas Shenk
        [price] => 49.99
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [title] => Test
        [author] => Eric Gross
        [price] => 100.00
    )
```

)

---

PHP For Fun And Profit
                        5
**Notice**:  Undefined index: 
                        5 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalProject\cart.php** on line **52**

3
**Notice**:  Undefined index: 
                        3 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalProject\cart.php** on line **52**

Title     Author     Price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at the source of your question, it seems there is a newline character before the number (so, it would be `"\n5"` instead of `5`, which logically cannot be found), can you confirm this? What does a `var_dump($cartedbook);` yield?

Comment: This is the output:

    `5string(27) " 5"`
    `3string(27) " 3"`

It does look like there is some type of character there...

EDIT: I found the error, i did have a newline on another .php file that added the values to the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Results from mysql queries are strings, even if they are integers in the database. This causes your `$bookarray` to be associated by numeric strings instead of numeric indexes, which your probably trying to use against it.

Try casting that ID as an int:

```
$bookarray[(int) $row['bookID']] = array(
```